# How to get notification when text pasted from clipboard into an edit box exceeds the maximum length?

Tags: delphi

I need to show a message to the user when text pasted from the clipboard into a `TEdit` control exceeds its maximum allowed length. But I would not like the program to check every time a new letter is typed, only when text is pasted.

How would I do this?

Comment: Subclass the edit class and listen for the `WM_PASTE` message.

Comment: The `TEdit` component has `MaxLenght` property, I think you should use it instead.

Comment: @Sami I know, but I need to show the message, that's what customer asks for

Comment: @niksrb If so, I would follow Victoria suggestion.

Comment: @Sami I agree, that would finish the job. Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: If you didn't limit your requirement to pasting the text, you would listen to the `EN_MAXTEXT` notification. That one is sent even when the user is typing in the edit control and reaches `MaxLength` (not only when pasting exceeds the length limit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclass the `TEdit` to handle the [`EN_MAXTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761684.aspx) notification:

> Sent when the current text insertion has exceeded the specified number of characters for the edit control. The text insertion has been truncated.

This applies to typing as well as pasting, and takes text selection into account for you.  For example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    procedure CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TEdit.CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.NotifyCode = EN_MAXTEXT then
    ShowMessage('Too much text!');
end;

end.
```

If you only want to handle pasting, then catch `WM_PASTE` to set a flag before calling `inherited`, then clear the flag when `inherited` exits, and if `EN_MAXTEXT` is issued while the flag is set then act accordingly:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    FIsPasting: Boolean;
    procedure CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
    procedure WMPaste(var Message: TMessage); message WM_PASTE;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TEdit.CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.NotifyCode = EN_MAXTEXT) and FIsPasting then
    ShowMessage('Too much text!');
end;

procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  FIsPasting := True;
  try 
    inherited;
  finally
    FIsPasting := False;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I was thinking of this too, but the OP has a requirement to get notification only when the text is pasted (as I understood). That might be my fault, as the original question said _"But I would not like program to check every time a new letter is inserted, but only when it's pasted text which is longer than maximum value"_.

Comment: @Victoria I haven't tried this yet, but maybe catch `WM_PASTE` to set a flag before calling `inherited`, then clear the flag when `inherited` exits. If `EN_MAXTEXT` is issued while the flag is set, act accordingly

Comment: That works and it's quite elegant idea! Another way is to calculate space for pasting (`MaxLength - GetTextLen + SelLength`) and compare it with clipboard length.

Comment: @Victoria I prefer to not calculate things manually when the OS can do it for me.

Comment: Me neither. I would prefer using your flag solution. I didn't want to steal your idea. @niksrb, consider accepting this answer.

Comment: @Victoria I have already used your idea to solve my problem, but I agree that this answer is more elegant and yes, maybe I should accept it for those who face same problem as me. Thank you both!

Answer (score 9):

Subclass the edit class and listen for the [**WM_PASTE**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028(v=vs.85).aspx) message. For example (for Unicode Delphi):

```
uses
  Vcl.Clipbrd;

type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    procedure WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  end;

implementation

procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste);
begin
  if (MaxLength > 0) and (Length(Clipboard.AsText) > MaxLength - GetTextLen + SelLength) then
    ShowMessage('Text is too long!');
  inherited;
end;
```

Another, little more efficient WinAPI variant (which doesn't copy the clipboard buffer but just queries its size), could be (also for Unicode Delphi):

```
type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    procedure WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  end;

implementation

procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste);
var
  Data: THandle;
begin
  if (MaxLength > 0) and OpenClipboard(0) then
  try
    Data := GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
    if (Data <> 0) and ((GlobalSize(Data) div SizeOf(Char)) - 1 > MaxLength - GetTextLen + SelLength) then
      ShowMessage('Text is too long!');
  finally
    CloseClipboard;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

If you wanted to prevent the text from being pasted into the control, remove the [**inherited**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Inherited) calls from the above examples.

Comment: As all this was your idea, I have to pick your answer, even @Sami has posted a good one also. Thanks again!

Comment: I wouldn't compare clipboard text length with MaxLength. If you do that, you have to take into account any possible text already in the edit and the selection etc..

Comment: You're right, @Sertac. Selection must be considered as well! This answer is no good. If you want, feel free to post your own. Otherwise I'll try to fix it later on.

Comment: Victoria, by calling `Inherited` in the end, the text will be pasted anyway which I don't think the OP want it (I guess).

Comment: @Sami, see my last words in this post. But it's wrong, anyway.

Comment: Victoria  answer is good for the question, which only wants to monitor pasted text length. I'd just use an arbitrary constant. Besides I disagree @Sami in that the paste operation should be aborted. The question only mentions showing a message.

Comment: @Sertac, added pastable space consideration. Thank you for your note!

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Clipbrd;

type
  TPasteEdit = class(TEdit)
    private
      FMaxPaste: Integer;
      procedure WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
    protected
    public
      constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    published
      property MaxPaste: Integer read FMaxPaste write FMaxPaste default 0;
      //You can define it or use MaxLength as well
  end;
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}



{ TPastEdit }

constructor TPasteEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FMaxPaste:= 0;
end;

procedure TPasteEdit.WMPaste(var Message: TWMPaste);
begin
  if Length(Clipboard.AsText) > FMaxPaste then
    ShowMessage('The text you paste is too long!') // Call inherited if you want to paste anyway
      else
        inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
  PasteEdit: TPasteEdit;
begin
  PasteEdit:= TPasteEdit.Create(Self);
  PasteEdit.Parent:= Self;
  PasteEdit.MaxPaste:= 3;
end;

end.
```